# RewriteCond and RewriteRule for .htaccess - always open as one unique URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I need is, whenever someone opens the site, no matter how they type the URL, the URL should always be opened the same, i.e. no matter someone types:

```
example.com
example.com/
www.example.com
www.example.com/
http://example.com
http://example.com/
http://www.example.com
http://www.example.com/
https://example.com
https://example.com/
https://www.example.com
https://www.example.com/
```

The site should always be opened as:

```
https://www.example.com/
```

I've already tried some RewriteCond and RewriteRule in .htaccess, but no success, the site won't open, saying too many redirects.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Here's the content of the .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Updated**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URL} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

> **If you want To Open Your Site as a SSL (`https://www.example.com`) try this code into a `.htaccess` file inside the website's `root` folder**

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

> **NOTE:**  First of All You Need to Activated SSL In Your `Account Management Panel (AMP)`

Comment: Same as above, it doesn't work if you type the URL as www.example.com or www.example.com/ or http://www.example.com or http://www.example.com/ it works only if you type it without the www. in the URL

Comment: @Ivco What is your actual domain name ? may i know

Comment: @Ivco Can you update Your question with Your `.htaccess` file code

Comment: I just updated the question with the .htaccess file's content.

Comment: @Ivco .. I Update my ans check

Answer (score 0):

I use this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Comment: It doesn't work if you type the URL with www. it works only if you type it without the www. in the URL

Answer (score 0):

Have it like this:

```
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# add www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=308,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^googlebase\.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*)$ index.php?route=error/not_found [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

While testing this change, completely clear browser cache.

Comment: Cleaned the whole browser cache, but getting "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS", althought it seems to redirects it correctly, I can see the URL getting changed in the address bar.

Comment: Nope, I emptied the whole content from the .htaccess file, and put in it only the code you've provided, so it's the exact code from your answer.

Comment: I've put the changed one you've edited, with 308, and still the same. There are no 301/302, just 308, and many of those, and at the end there is: (failed) net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Comment: Yeap, always getting 308 repeatedly, Apache v2.4.10, and no proxy.

Comment: Just tried it, and now I'm getting a blank page, with a "308 Permanent Redirect" title, and "Permanent Redirect" h1 text, and "The document has moved here" p text, where "here" is a link to the actual https URL.

Comment: I've changed it to 301, cleaned all the cache, and getting "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".

Comment: Enable rewrite log and provide relevant log entries with this request.